# Implementing Webflow JS in WordPress

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement [Webflow's horizontal scrolling](https://webflow.com/blog/creating-horizontal-scrolling) in WordPress.

HTML Webflow export (working): https://horizontalscrolling.demo.site/webflow/horizontal-scrolling/

My WordPress attempt (not working): https://horizontalscrolling.demo.site/horizontal-scrolling/

As you can see in the WordPress version, scrolling down does not make the images in the purple section move horizontally.

My questions are:

1. What can be done to fix this JS error in the console?

```
webflow.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tram' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (webflow.js:16)
    at n (webflow.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webflow.js:7)
    at n (webflow.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webflow.js:16)
    at n (webflow.js:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webflow.js:16)
    at n (webflow.js:7)
    at webflow.js:7
    at webflow.js:7
```

2. [webflow.js](https://horizontalscrolling.demo.site/webflow/horizontal-scrolling/js/webflow.js) is a huge file (155.3 KB). Surely, the actual relevant code is only a small fraction. How do I identify what part it is so I can use just that?

Here's how I loaded the JS in WordPress:

Code in a custom functionality plugin:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'webflow', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/webflow.js', '', '1.0.0', true );
```

where main.js is:

```
(function($) {
    $("html").attr("data-wf-page", "5c37e0e1e3cff796d50e5cca");
    $("html").attr("data-wf-site", "5c37e0e1e3cff72e980e5cc5");
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working.

I had to add a couple more data attributes in the HTML markup to match those in the Webflow export.

Then replace both the instances of `window.$` with `window.jQuery` in webflow.js. An alternative to this to add `var $ = jQuery` at the beginning of that file.

Now need to figure out how to trim webflow.js to just the actual code that is needed..

Comment: +1 upvote thank you very much, I found this to work when using `webflow.js` exported file with Drupal 9 (9.0.7).  My menu built in webflow its markup re-used in a `menu.html.twig` template file didn't work on mobile. When ran a search replace with your search/replace suggestion, I too found 2 instances that needed changing from `window.$` to `window.jQuery` in `webflow.js` Then clearing Drupal cache and that webflow markup in that template now works on a mobile width screen.

Comment: I should add another helpful note. I came across `"Oops! This page has improperly configured forms. Please contact your website administrator to fix this issue"` and traced this to the minified `webform.js` in the webform export html/js/css that I wanted to use direct with my Drupal site. To stop this error happening, I renamed `w-form` to something else and added a css class of that name to the css. What this does is stop the `webform.js` from looking for `w-form` in the html to raise that error on it. So this means that the export can be used in non-webflow systems: Drupal or Wordpress :)